# VBA to engage "browse" button on IE and provide folder location for the file

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

I'm stuck at the point where I need to "upload" the .txt files to IE browser. It seems that calling the button 'browse' through `.getelementsbyname` does not work [the element in question i.e. the 'browse' button is `name="dataFile"` [as in the source code below]. Moreover, once 'browse' reacts I need to provide .txt file location and then `.click` Open on that window.

I would be greatly obliged if someone could guide me towards resolution.

```
</td>
<td valign="top">
<div class="edl_radio float-left">
<label class="edl_rd">
<input type="radio" name="appendOrOverwriteListDataSet" value="appendToProposedListDataSet" checked />
<span></span>
</label>
<label>Append</label>
</div>
<div class="edl_radio float-left">
<label class="edl_rd">
<input type="radio" name="appendOrOverwriteListDataSet" value="overwriteListDataSet"  />
<span></span>
</label>
<label>
Replace
</label>
</div>
<br class="clearfloat" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">
</td>
<td>
<div class="floatleft">
Upload Data File
<input type="file" name="dataFile" size="27" />  
</div>
<div class="float-left">
<b>OR</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="floatleft">
Enter Data:&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="floatleft">
<textarea name="listData" cols="1" style="width:200px; height:50px;"></textarea>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="button secondary-btn" type="button" id="upload1" name="upload1" value="Upload" onclick="javascript:processForm(this.form, 3);"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have you tried to SendKeys the file name to the input field without worrying about clicking?

Comment: Hi, I tried this [doesn't work - even when the 'browse button' is highlighted sending {ENTER} to it does nothing]: Dim wBrowse As Object
Set wBrowse = IE.Document.getelementsbyname("dataFile")
wBrowse.Focus
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Comment: But what if you say Application.SendKeys("PathHere/file.ext")

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately this function does nothing.

Comment: Sorry. I hope someone else has a better idea.